# optimize the query which is using conditional operator with ordering clause in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to do optimize this query. I have give statistics for using tables.

products and products_categories table have around 5 laks record. But for below mentioned category it has 1600 record. I have create slots for this 1600 records. Every product can have minimum 1 slot and maximum 10 slots. But slot table have around 3 laks record. slot table can have already expire slots also. I want to get products, which are going to expire soon come first and rest of the products come behind of this products.

I have created index for end_time colume. But I used conditional operator, so index not using in this query. I want to optimize this query. kindly tell me the best way.

```
EXPLAIN 
    SELECT products.*, IF(slot.end_time > NOW(), 1, 2) as order_by_end_time 
    FROM products 
        INNER JOIN products_categories ON products_categories.productid = products.productid 
        LEFT JOIN (select product_id, end_time from slot where end_time>now() order by end_time) as slot ON slot.product_id = products.productid
    WHERE products_categories.categoryid='4410' 
        AND products.saleid = 2 
    GROUP BY products.productid 
    ORDER BY order_by_end_time ASC ,  slot.end_time ASC
```

Comment: Where is the output of the explain statement?

Comment: I could not upload explain statement images..

Comment: Paste the text of the explain statement into question. Image won't be needed just  the text output.

Comment: I could not upload explain statement images..
select_type table              type   possible_keys             key     key_len  ref     rows    Extra
PRIMARY     product_categories ref    PRI,cpm,productid cpm     4        const   1523    Using Index; Using temporary; Using filesort
PRIMARY     products         eq_ref PRI,saleid            PRIMARY 4        xcart1  1       Using where
PRIMARY     <derived2>         ALL    NULL                      NULL    NULL     NULL    385113  Using where
DERIVED     slot         ALL    i_end_time                NULL    NULL     NULL    423280  Using filesort

Comment: id  select_type  table  type  possible_keys  key  key_len  ref  rows  Extra
1  PRIMARY  xcart_products_categories  ref  PRIMARY,cpm,productid,orderby,pm  cpm  4  const  1523  Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
1  PRIMARY  xcart_products  eq_ref  PRIMARY,saleid  PRIMARY  4  wwwbvira_xcart.xcart_products_categories.productid  1  Using where
1  PRIMARY  <derived2>  ALL  NULL NULL NULL NULL 395802  
2  DERIVED  bvira_megahour_time_slot  ALL  i_end_time  NULL NULL NULL 398907  Using filesort

Answer (score 0):

id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY     xcart_products_categories   ref     PRIMARY,cpm,productid,orderby,pm    cpm     4   const   1523    Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   PRIMARY     xcart_products  eq_ref  PRIMARY,saleid  PRIMARY     4   wwwbvira_xcart.xcart_products_categories.productid  1   Using where
1   PRIMARY       ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    395802
2   DERIVED     bvira_megahour_time_slot    ALL     i_end_time  NULL    NULL    NULL    398907  Using filesort